# Component not re rendering even after calling the setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rerender, react-dropzone, react-state-management

I have a react component in which user can upload Image and he's also shown the preview of uploaded image. He can delete the image by clicking delete button corresponding to Image. I am using react-dropzone for it. Here's the code:

```
class UploadImage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onDrop = this.onDrop.bind(this);
    this.deleteImage = this.deleteImage.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      filesToBeSent: [],
      filesPreview: [],
      printCount: 10,
    };
  }

  onDrop(acceptedFiles, rejectedFiles) {
    const filesToBeSent = this.state.filesToBeSent;
    if (filesToBeSent.length < this.state.printCount) {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        filesToBeSent: prevState.filesToBeSent.concat([{acceptedFiles}])
      }));
      console.log(filesToBeSent.length);
      for (var i in filesToBeSent) {
        console.log(filesToBeSent[i]);
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          filesPreview: prevState.filesPreview.concat([
            <div>
              <img src={filesToBeSent[i][0]}/>
              <Button variant="fab" aria-label="Delete" onClick={(e) => this.deleteImage(e,i)}>
                <DeleteIcon/>
              </Button>
            </div>
          ])
        }));
      }
    } else {
      alert("you have reached the limit of printing at a time")
    }
  }

  deleteImage(e, id) {
    console.log(id);
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({filesToBeSent: this.state.filesToBeSent.filter(function(fid) {
        return fid !== id
    })});
}

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Dropzone onDrop={(files) => this.onDrop(files)}>
          <div>
            Upload your Property Images Here
          </div>
        </Dropzone>
        {this.state.filesToBeSent.length > 0 ? (
          <div>
            <h2>
              Uploading{this.state.filesToBeSent.length} files...
            </h2>
          </div>
        ) : null}
        <div>
          Files to be printed are: {this.state.filesPreview}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default UploadImage;
```

My Question is my component is not re-rendering even after adding or removing an Image. Also, I've taken care of not mutating state arrays directly. Somebody, please help.

Comment: Consider providing a working demo to debug. `(files) => this.onDrop(files)` is redundant, a callback is already bound. `prevState.filesToBeSent.concat([{acceptedFiles}])` - this looks fishy, there will be an object with `acceptedFiles` property. It doesn't look there's a need for it. Shouldn't it be `[...prevState.filesToBeSent, ...acceptedFiles]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this, I have used ES6

[image: Edit 7myoo2x226]    .

Comment: Thank you so much, sir! So you moved the function for displaying image previews inside render. Also, you updated the way of changing states. But can you explain me why my way of changing state was wrong in onDrop() function?

Comment: You have to think and code in react way not jQuery way like constructing html and append html into element and also keeping html in state isn't necessary in your case which cause unnessary complexity if you have large html

Comment: I have one more doubt... Didn't you mutate the state array directly in `deleteImage()` function. Sorry for the too mainstream questions as I am totally new to React

Comment: this.state.filesToBeSent.filter always return new array, check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter